# How do I control which instance of a background script responds to message passing?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome Extension that creates an iframe on the web page you are currently viewing. The visibility of this iframe is toggled by clicking on the extension's icon. That all is working well.

Messages from the user interactions on the iframe are passed to a background script, where API calls to a third-party are executed. The responses to the API calls are then passed back to the iframe, and handled accordingly.

When the extension is running, and the iframe is loaded in multiple tabs, it appears as though multiple instances of the background script are also running. I have found that when the iframe passes a message to the background script, it is being processed X number of times, where X is equal to the number of tabs I have open.

For example, the user clicks a button, which sends a message to the background script:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "getData"}, function(r) {
        alert(r);
        //display the API response to the user
    });
});
```

The Background Script has a message listener much like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.message == "getData") {
        makeAPICall(function(r){
            sendResponse(r);
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Since I don't want the API call to be sent multiple times, how can I control which instance of the background script should be responsible for executing the the API call and responding to the message, and ensure that this instance is the only one that does so?

Comment: There is only one instance of the background script. The one that's declared via `background` key in manifest.json. If you load the background script elsewhere then don't do it as it's wrong.

Comment: I think that was the issue. In my popup.html file, I had previously referenced my background script in the head. I have since removed that reference, and it seems to have cleared up the issue I was seeing. Major thanks to @wOxxOm for pointing me in the right direction!